# Using a field to define font size in ArcGIS 10.x

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling

Is there a way to use label expressions in ArcGIS 10.x to specify the font size for a label from the values in a field?

So as an example, I have a point dataset which I wish to label, and within the attribute table there is a numeric field called "size" which holds the size I want the label for that feature to be.

I've managed to use an expression to specify a font and a single size for the whole dataset

```
"<FNT name = 'Arial' size = '12' >" & [gml_id] & "</FNT>"
```

But if I try to replace the number 12 with the name of the field which holds the font sizes, the code doesn't work i.e.

```
"<FNT name = 'Arial' size = [size]  >" & [gml_id] & "</FNT>"
```

The above expression prints the expression as the label, rather than the values from the "gml_id" field.  So this made me think that it was interpreting the whole thing as a string because it's all in double quotes, however removing the quotes gives me a syntax error.

```
"<FNT name = 'Arial' size = '[size]'  >" & [gml_id] & "</FNT>"
```

The above expression gives me no label.

```
"<FNT name = 'Arial' size = "[size]"  >" & [gml_id] & "</FNT>"
```

The above expression gives me a syntax error.

Anybody know where I am going wrong or even if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost nailed it down.

```
"<FNT name = 'Arial' size = '" & [sizefield]  & "'  > " & [gml_id] & " </FNT>"
```